# Change screen size using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

Using [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)'s mobile-first experience, I have developed a responsive design. Now, my client requires an explicit link "View desktop version" in the footer, when the site is opened in mobile or tablets.

There seems to be two options:

- *Drop foundation* and create new CSS files (perhaps extract selected rules from foundation core CSS for grid); one for desktop and one for mobile. Then load CSS file based on cookies value or URL query. (Long method)
- Modify the screen size (max-width, min-width ..) using JavaScript, so the media query get wrong info and loads right results? (imagination)

Is the second option possible? Is there another (easy) way to do it?

Comment: "so the media query get wrong info and loads right results (imagination)" I LOL'ed

Comment: This *might* be of interest:  http://menacingcloud.com/?c=responsiveViewport

Comment: @vulcanraven well how 'bout that.

Comment: @Annie Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @Trolleymusic, its not working in IE10 mobile and Andriod browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can modify the meta tag. I did it for a project a while back and I've got a piece of script/plugin for it on github: https://github.com/Trolleymusic/minWidth - I've just updated it now with some demos for you.

**You must include Modernizr or it won't work**

You just run it like this:

```
minWidth(x);
```

Where x is the min width you want it to be.

On your phone check out the difference between the two demo files:

http://waynedurack.com/minWidth/demos/with.html

vs

http://waynedurack.com/minWidth/demos/without.html